# Regex expression to find a string meeting certain criteria

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

I need a regular expression to find a string meeting certain criteria:

- string starts with 55
- string is all numeric and dashes
- the number of digits in the string is between 10 and 14

what I do is loop through an array of text to find a string that meets the criteria above, extract it and assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated as per comment

```
55(-?\d-?){8,12}
```

http://regexr.com/39uic

Comment: Not quite. The string can be all numeric or numeric with dashes. For example: 55-90-0999-12 or 55490342300 or 55-567-4050-00001

Comment: I changed it to 55(-?\d-?){10,19} and it works pretty well for me.